# force closes at multiple click

Tags: android, android-widget

i have completed a project successfully, the problem was when the user hit simultaneously 2 or more buttons the app get crashes, also when app fetches data from service that time when user hits other widget it get force close.

the error log such as..

```
12-13 12:42:03.763: W/webcore(576): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
12-13 12:44:52.284: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 12:44:52.284: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-13 12:44:52.284: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 12:44:52.284: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 12:44:52.284: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-13 12:44:52.284: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
```

is there any possible way to put the request queue in android code?

how i handle force close in android app?

thank you.

Comment: Use progress bar while fetching data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to make more change in your code then just use a flag to check is server request is currently executing or completed as:

```
public static boolean status=true;
    getdatabuttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                   // check flag here before makeing 
                   //new request to server
                   if(status==true){
                      status=false;
                      // get data here
                         getDatafromServer();
                    }
                   else{
                    // show message already downloading data from server
                    }
        }
         });
```

your get data method for making data request to server

```
public void getDatafromServer(){

//your code here for getting data
//....

// after getting data change flag
status=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> use async class when you are getting data from the service.
>   or use handlers to handle this kind of crashes.
>   otherwise disable the buttons until you get the data from the service...

Answer (score 0):

Use asyn class for getting data from service,surrounded the button with try/catch to handle the exception.